# html.beginform doesn't post back to controller, Error Loading Page message?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.beginform

I have been trying post a value back to the controller so I can update a balance elsewhere, but I cannot get it to work. I get a message

> *Error Loading Page*

All I want is a `double` value, but to be honest, I would just like to get the code into the controller in the first instance.

My `.cshtml` is like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Deposit", "AccountController", FormMethod.Post))
{
       <fieldset>
        <legend>Deposit Amount</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
       <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>

        </fieldset>

}
```

And the controller is:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Deposit()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Deposit(LoginModel model)
    {

        // do things

        return View(model);
    }
```

I am new to MVC. I know the view code doesn't have the amount value that I ultimately would like to use, or I may add it to a model and just pass that, but I cannot get it to the controller at all.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just slightly off on the naming conventions of MVC. Assuming the name of your controller class is `AccountController`, you should specify that minus the "Controller" part in the `BeginForm()` method:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Deposit", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: one last thing, is it possible to get the data entered into the text box and store it in my model before I post ?

Comment: @Racing57: Normally that doesn't happen until after the form submission (which is passing the form values to MVC, which will bind them to your `LoginModel`).

Comment: thanks Cory, I have got that now... and it all seems to work fine. I just added the following

Comment: thanks Cory, I have got that now... and it all seems to work fine. I just added the following
      

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DepositAmount)

and this does what I need it to do now... thanks.